# MS Access Sum #Error

Tags: ms-access

I have an access form and subform that i created using a query. Then, through design view, I created a text box, and entered a rather long nested iif that referred to other fields in the subform.

Now, I want to use the SUM function to add up the values (results of iff) in the  created text boxes, each which have different values. I have tried everything I can think of, but it always comes up with #Error! no matter what I do.

Comment: It is always best to post code.

Comment: You may want to start from the inside out of your iff statement and verify that each piece works one at a time.  And if your iif statement is really that long, you could consider writing a vba procedure and calling that instead.  
If you post the iif statement, we might be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when I added more than one Function type in a query, it crash what I need to do first is for example create the iff clause to mark or create a new field and put a text like "YES".

then in other query apply the sum on the fields that matches with "YES".

Try by separate it.